# Efficiency in drawing arbitrary meshes with OpenGL (Qt)

Tags: qt, opengl

I am in the process of coding a level design tool in **Qt** with **OpenGL** (for a relevant example see Valve's Hammer, as Source games are what I'm primarily designing this for) and have currently written a few classes to represent 3D objects (vertices, edges, faces). I plan to implement an *"object"* class which ties the three together, keeps track of its own vertices, etc.

After having read up on rendering polygons on http://open.gl, I have a couple of questions regarding the most efficient way to render the content. Bear in mind that this is a level editor, so I am anticipating needing to render a large number of objects with arbitrary shapes and numbers of vertices/faces.

Edit: Updated to be less broad.

- At what point would be the best point to create the VBO? The Qt OpenGL example creates a VBO when a viewport is initialized, but I'd expect it to be inefficient to create a close for each viewport.
- Regarding the submitted answer, would it be a sensible idea to create one VBO for geometry, another for mesh models, etc? What happens if/when a VBO overflows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBOs should be re-/initialized whenever there's a need for it. Consider VBOs as memory pools. So you'd not allocate one VBO per object, but group similar objects into a single VBO. When you run out of space in one VBO you allocate a another one.

Today's GPUs are optimized for rendering indexed triangles. So GL_TRIANGLES will suffice in 90% of all cases.

Frankly modern OpenGL implementations completely ignore the buffer object access mode. So many programs did made ill use of that parameter, that it became more efficient to profile the usage pattern and adjust driver behavior toward that. However it's still a good idea to use the right mode. And in your case it's GL_STATIC_DRAW.

Comment: OK, thanks. So essentially it doesn't matter too much what renderables you use a specific VBO for, the sole purpose of one being that it keeps the data on (or at least near) the GPU so that it can be accessed quickly? Is there any way I can know when a VBO is full?

Comment: @x6herbius: Well, since you initialize the VBO with a given size all you have to do is track its occupation with data. Effectively a VBO represents a contiguous chunk of memory, which can be populated with arbitrary data. Of course to reach maximal performance you should align the data in it. So for example floats should be aligned toward `sizeof(float) = 4` addresses. I recommend that before actually allocating and populating a VBO you first collect some statistics about all the data to load and determine the allocation pattern from that.